# jquery dialog - push the background content down

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm having a strange problem with the jquery dialog popup that I'm hoping someone here can help.  The pop up codes looks like below.  It works fine except for one thing.  When the pop-up is displayed, it will sometimes push the background content down by about the height of the the dialog window.  Is there a way to prevent this from happenning?

```
$("#searchPopUp").dialog({
    modal: true,
    bgiframe: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    position:{ my: "center", at: "center", of: window },
    title: 'Choose one search criteria and<br/>populate the corresponding field below:',
    width: 400,
    close: function( event, ui ) {},
    buttons: {
        "Search": function() {
            $("#viewDevicesSearchForm\\:searchCommandLink").click();
        }, 
        "Close": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }  
} 
});
```

[image: Before Dialog widow]

[image: After Dialog window - Notice the background table is being pushed down a bit]

Comment: try changing bgiframe: to true?  could you post a fiddle if that doesn't work?  Its hard to imagine exactly what youre talking about it or even test a fix.

Comment: Still doing the same thing after changing bgiframe to true.  I added a before and after images to show what I meaning by pushing the content down.  In the after image, you can see a big gap between the back-ground table and the top of the page.

Comment: is this browser specific?

Comment: I use both IE9 and FF13.0.1 and I seems to recall it happened on both browsers.  But I tested it a few times this morning and the problem only occurred on FF.

Comment: can you link or jsfiddle?

Comment: it is an intranet link.  So, there is no way to access from outside our network.  I've never done jsfiddle.  I'll try to see how it work.

Comment: basically just work out how to replicate your issue without recreating your whole project.  Sometimes its easy, and sometimes is not, but it makes it MUCH easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because jquery sets position to relative, and then moves the popup to the right place using top and left. I found two ways to fix the problem:

1) The easier of the two: set margin-bottom of the dialog container to negative its height.

```
popup.dialog({
            ...other options...,

            open : function() {
                popup.css('margin-bottom', 0 - popup.height());
            },
        });
```

2) For the dialog container, set the position to absolute and adjust the top and left. To put it in the right place, add the offset position of where it is getting placed to the top value that jquery set. The calculation is similar for left.This should do it, but different parameters to the dialog may require different calculations.